# What and where in the notebooks of Ramanujan is this series?

Tags: number-theory, sequences-and-series, reference-request

The wikipedia page on Ramanujan contains the following series:

$$
1 - 5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3 + 9\left(\frac{1\times3}{2\times4}\right)^3 - 13\left(\frac{1\times3\times5}{2\times4\times6}\right)^3 + \cdots = \frac{2}{\pi}
$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(4n+1) \left[ \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right]^3=\frac{2}{\pi}$$

Unfortunately, there is no reference as to where I can find this series in his notebooks (or in the 5-volume Springer set, for that matter), which is basically what I am after.

Also, though I do now study math, I am still a freshman, so I don't know enough about infinite series to be able to classify this series. *Does it belong to a type of series? Is there a general class of series to which this series belongs?*

Generally, I am very keen to know more about this series.

Comment: Looks hypergeometric. There's a starting point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As suggested by Anon it appears in the "Hypergeometric series" chapter of Hardy's book "Ramanujan" (formula (1.2)-(1.4) of page 7 and (7.4.2) and others of page 105). You may 'look inside' Hardy's book at [amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821820230).

Ramanujan published an article in 1914 ["Modular Equations and Approximations to $\pi$"](http://books.google.com/books?id=oSioAM4wORMC&pg=PA36) that contains some related examples (28),(29),...

The formula appears in Berndt's ["Ramanujan's Notebooks II"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038796794X) page 23s (search 'Example' and click on 'page 16').

A search of [Dougall-Ramanujan Identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dougall-RamanujanIdentity.html) and variants could be helpful too since your equation is a special case of this identity (follow the Morley's formula [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MorleysFormula.html) for another simple example).

See the Tract of Bailey ['Generalized Hypergeometric Series'](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/math/Bailey%20W.N.%20Generalized%20Hypergeometric%20Series%20%281964%29%28L%29%28T%29%2859s%29.pdf) for many more hypergeometric identities and the examples provided page 96.

Hoping it helped,

Comment: Thank you Raymond! Those identities are seriously sick.

Comment: @Peter: Yeah Ramanujan is a great generator of these kinds of things! :-) (Bailey's book is fine for that too...)

Answer (score 3):

I'm seriously late for this party but,  to address one of your questions, there are infinitely many formulas

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{An+B}{C^n} \left[ \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right]^3=\frac{1}{\pi}$$

where $A,B,C$ are algebraic numbers. A few others are

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\pi}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{6n+1}{2^{3n}} \left[ \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right]^3\\
\frac{4}{\pi}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{6n+1}{2^{2n}} \left[ \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right]^3\\
\frac{16}{\pi}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{42n+5}{2^{6n}} \left[ \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right]^3\end{aligned}$$

and so on. They belong to Ramanujan's fourth class of pi formulas. (I discussed the Wikipedia example in my blog [*Ramanujan Once A Day*](http://ramanujandaily.blogspot.com/2016/09/entry-28.html).)